# What is the range of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ if $-2\leq x \leq 2$

Tags: inequality

What is the range of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ if $-2\leq x \leq 2$?

My try:

$-2\leq x \leq 2$

$\Rightarrow \frac{-1}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{-5}{2}\leq x+\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{5}{2}$

Am i correct or wrong?If not,please help me solve this.

Comment: Hint: For $x=\frac{1}{100}$ you get $x+\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{100}+100 = 100.01$ which is not in your given range.

Comment: Start with just positive $x$ (for negative values, the expression just gets a global negative component).  If $0 \leq x \leq 2$, then $\tfrac 1x \geq \tfrac 12$, so you cannot just add the inequalities.

Comment: You are making two mistakes: wrongly estimating the range of $1/x$, and treating $x$ and $1/x$ as if they could take any value in their respective range independently of each other. (Not counting the typo in the second line.)

Comment: A sketch of $y=x +\frac1x$ might help you see the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$, the expression makes no sense. Furthermore, the function $f(x)=x+\frac1x$ is odd, so it suffices to consider the interval $(0,2]$.

The derivative
$$f'(x)=1-\frac1{x^2}$$
is negative at $(0,1)$ and positive at $(1,2]$. At $x=1$ there is a minimum and $f(1)=2$, and
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty$$
therefore, the range for $f(x)$ at $(0,2]$ is $[2,\infty)$.

Can you finish? Remember that $f$ is odd.

It would be good also to notice that $f$ reaches every intermediate value, due to its continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can consider the first derivative of $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ to know how this function varies.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$ using [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),

$$\dfrac{x+\dfrac1x}2\ge\sqrt{x\cdot\dfrac1x}\iff x+\dfrac1x\ge2$$

The equality occurs if $x=\dfrac1x\iff x=1$ as $x>0$

Now consider two values of $x,a>b>0$

$a+\dfrac1a-\left(b+\dfrac1b\right)=(a-b)\dfrac{ab-1}{ab}$ will be $>0$
if $(ab-1)ab>0\iff ab>1$

So, we shall continue getting higher values of $x+\dfrac1x$ if $ab>1$

If $x<0,$ set $-x=y$

Comment: +1. But I think, you should mention the term _inequality of arithmetic and geometric means_

Comment: You also forgot to check that equality is possible (and the lower bound tight) in the allowed range of $x$, and that the expression is unbounded above.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Please find the revised answer

Comment: Isn't it enough to say that $1/x$ is unbounded ?

Answer (score 1):

If $x < 0$,
then
$x+\frac1{x}
=-(|x|+\frac1{|x|})
$,
so we only have to look at
$x > 0$.

If $x > 0$,
$x+\frac1{x}
=x+\frac1{x}-2+2
=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{\frac1{x}})^2+2
$,
so
$x+\frac1{x}
\ge 2
$
and equals $2$
for $x = 1$.

Since
$\frac1{x}
\to \infty
$
as
$x \to 0$,
$x+\frac1{x}
$
can be arbitrarily large.

Therefore,
the range for $x > 0$
is
$[2,\infty)$
and the range for
$[-2, 2]\backslash\{0\}
$
is
$[2,\infty)
\cup
(-\infty, -2]
$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $f$'s derivative, $\pm1$ are critical points. And $\pm2$ are endpoints of the domain. And the function is not defined at $0$. Since $$\begin{align}f(-2)&=-2.5&f(-1)&=-2&\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)&=-\infty\\
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)&=\infty&f(1)&=2&f(2)&=2.5\end{align}$$ the range is $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.